# scroll bar on windows without bar

Tags: html, css

I have created a top scroll bar. So when you make the panel smaller you need to scroll to see the rest of the menu.

This works fine on Safari on the Mac and on Google OS BUT not on a Windows computer, Instead, you get a nasty grey scroll panel at the bottom of the blue panel.

Is there a way to get rid of this please but still be able to scroll as shown in the example.

Hope you can help

Thanks

Tim

```
/Users/timcross/Desktop/111111.png
```

I cannot turn off overflow-x: scroll as I need this to scroll so not sure how to get around this

https://jsfiddle.net/timcross/hf8byg2r/

Comment: Code relevant to your question belongs directly _into_ your question, not just dumped onto an external site. And please tag appropriately, this surely isn’t a `php` issue - tag removed, `css` added instead.

Answer (score 0):

scroll panel is always visible because of the CSS property overflow-x and the overflow-y property has the value of "scroll",
this consider as the block always needs scroll,
you can change it to auto, then it will consider the correct behavior and add scroll panel if needed.

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

Change to

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

same for the `overflow-y`